# Tall crawl space; what could I do to help keep the house warm?

Tags: insulation

I have a crawl space that is 5’ tall. Insulation in floor joists. Is there anything else I could do to help my house stay warm?

Comment: Craw space is only one of many areas of a house.  The whole house needs to be checked.  Drafts, insulation in the walls and ceiling, doors/windows.  Most houses probably can use more insulation in the walls and ceiling(scary), reducing drafts and improving weatherstripping of doors/windows can help.

Comment: This is too open ended. You could provide the status of insulation in the walls, ceilngs, mateial used for walls and ceilings, details of windows, doors, glazing, temperature inside as compared to outside etc.

Comment: vented crawl or unvented?  in the old times you'd just put farm animals under there, smells horrible but does add heat.